# How to reset all values in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

```
{"green": 0, "y3": 1, "m@tt": 0, "newaccount": 0, "egg": 0, "results": 0, "dan": 0, "Lewis": 0, "NewAccount2": 0, "testyear3": 1, "testyear6": 0, "NewAccount1": 0, "testyear4": 0, "testyear5": 0, "Matt1": 0, "swag": 1, "lewis": 1, "matt": 1, "notin": 0}
```

this is the dictionary defined as 'completeddict'.
What I want to do, is to change ALL values no matter what they are called to 0. 
However bear in mind that new account names will be added at any point as 'keys' so I cannot manually do "completeddict[green] = 0", "completeddict[lewis] = 0", etc etc.

Is there any way to have python change ALL values within a dictionary back to 0?

EDIT: Unfortunately I do not want to create a new dictionary - I want to keep it called 'completeddict' as the program needs to use the dictionary defined as 'completeddict' at many points in the program.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding a fundamental concept in Python: if you have a dict called `completeddict` and then you say `completeddict=something_new` then the rest of your code will use something_new without any issue.

Comment: **See also**: equivalent question and answers for PHP http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217160

Answer (score 44):

Another option is to use [`.fromkeys()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys):

> fromkeys(seq[, value])
>
> Create a new dictionary with keys from seq and values set to value.

```
d = d.fromkeys(d, 0)
```

Demo:

```
>>> d = {"green": 0, "y3": 1, "m@tt": 0, "newaccount": 0, "egg": 0, "results": 0, "dan": 0, "Lewis": 0, "NewAccount2": 0, "testyear3": 1, "testyear6": 0, "NewAccount1": 0, "testyear4": 0, "testyear5": 0, "Matt1": 0, "swag": 1, "lewis": 1, "matt": 1, "notin": 0}
>>> d.fromkeys(d, 0)
{'newaccount': 0, 'swag': 0, 'notin': 0, 'NewAccount1': 0, 'Matt1': 0, 'testyear4': 0, 'Lewis': 0, 'dan': 0, 'matt': 0, 'results': 0, 'm@tt': 0, 'green': 0, 'testyear5': 0, 'lewis': 0, 'NewAccount2': 0, 'y3': 0, 'testyear3': 0, 'egg': 0, 'testyear6': 0}
```

Comment: +1, one of my favs. Just make sure that you don't do `{}.fromkeys(d, [])`

Comment: This will work here, but it's worth remembering that all values are the *same* `value`, and so if `value` were mutable -- say an empty list -- you'll get into trouble.

Answer (score 15):

Sure, its pretty easy:

```
newDict = {key: 0 for key in completeddict}
```

This is dictionary comprehension and is equivalent to:

```
newDict = {}
for key in completeddict:
    newDict[key] = 0
```

These dict comprehensions were introduced in v2.7, so older vesions will need to use the expanded form.

Comment: The `.keys()` is unnecessary.

Comment: That second form is important if you are using older Python2. Weren't dict comprehensions added in 2.7?

Comment: Python 2.6 final came out in 2008; at some point people will have to upgrade.  And since even Python 2.4 supports generator expressions, `dict((k,0) for k in completedict)` would be an almost-as-concise alternative.

Comment: I get the error `    for key in y6completeddict:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'y6completeddict' referenced before assignment` when trying this.

Comment: @user3112327, if this answer fixed your problem, please mark it as "accepted" so future readers can quickly find the answer

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want to create a new dict, it seems like all you need is a simple two-line loop, unless I'm missing something:

```
for key in completeddict.keys():
    completeddict[key] = 0
```

Answer (score 5):

A form that will work in virtually any Python version is just use the `dict` constructor with a list comprehension or generator:

```
>>> d={"green": 10, "y3": 11, "m@tt": 12, "newaccount": 22, "egg": 55, "results": 0, "dan": 0, "Lewis": 0, "NewAccount2": 0, "testyear3": 1, "testyear6": 0, "NewAccount1": 0, "testyear4": 0, "testyear5": 0, "Matt1": 0, "swag": 1, "lewis": 1, "matt": 1, "notin": 0}
>>> d=dict((k, 0) for k in d)
>>> d
{'newaccount': 0, 'swag': 0, 'notin': 0, 'NewAccount1': 0, 'Matt1': 0, 'testyear4': 0, 'Lewis': 0, 'dan': 0, 'matt': 0, 'results': 0, 'm@tt': 0, 'green': 0, 'testyear5': 0, 'lewis': 0, 'NewAccount2': 0, 'y3': 0, 'testyear3': 0, 'egg': 0, 'testyear6': 0}
```

Which you can then use with a mutable argument or some form of callable:

```
>>> d=dict((k, list()) for k in d)
```

Now each element of `d` is a new list (or whatever else mutable or not you would want to set the value portion of the tuple to be).

Comment: Ha!  You beat me to the mutable-argument issue, but I beat you to this! ;-)

Comment: @DSM: You usually do ;-}

Answer (score 1):

Adding to **alecxe** asnwer,

your dictionary is,

```
completeddict = {"green": 0, "y3": 1, "m@tt": 0, "newaccount": 0, "egg": 0, "results": 0, "dan": 0, "Lewis": 0, "NewAccount2": 0, "testyear3": 1, "testyear6": 0, "NewAccount1": 0, "testyear4": 0, "testyear5": 0, "Matt1": 0, "swag": 1, "lewis": 1, "matt": 1, "notin": 0}
```

now this dictionary can be updated with default values,

```
completeddict.update({}.fromkeys(completeddict,0)
```

Done. your completeddict is updated with default value for all keys.

Ex:

```
a = {'x':2,'y':4}
print id(a)  
print a
a.update({}.fromkeys(a,0))
print id(a)
print a
```

Output:

```
42612608     <--- id of dict 'a'
{'y': 4, 'x': 2}     <--- dict 'a' before updation
42612608     <--- id of dict 'a'   
{'y': 0, 'x': 0}     <--- dict 'a' after updation
```

It can be observed that id of the dictionary same even after it is updated with default values.

Answer (score 0):

`completeddict.clear()` should reset the entries. Check [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html).

Comment: OP wants to `change ALL values` to 0 and not delete all the keys and values from the dict. This is a good approach to completely empty a dict but not for what OP needs.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation where the dictionary could itself have nested dictionary and list values and all values that were not of type dictionary/list needed to be set to a default value:

```
def Clear(e1,defaultValue):
  if type(e1) is dict:
    return {k:Clear(e1[k], defaultValue) for k in e1.keys()}
  elif type(e1) is list:
    return [Clear(v,defaultValue) for v in e1]
  else:
    return defaultValue
```