# How to set dictionary values to zero in Julia

Tags: julia

I would like to set all the values of a dictionary to zero. In Python you can use the [.fromkeys()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys) function to do this (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22991888/how-to-reset-all-values-in-a-dictionary) SO question). How can this be done in Julia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `replace` function comes to mind. It takes a function as first argument that takes a pair as argument and returns the modified pair:

```
d_new = replace(kv -> kv[1] => 0, d)
```

Here, each pair `kv` from `d` is replaced by `kv[1] => 0`, where `kv[1]` is the key and `0` the new associated value.
Note that the mutating variant `replace!` is also available for in-place replacement.

EDIT: another possibility when the dictionary has to be mutated is:

```
map!(x->0, values(d))
```

Answer (score 2):

Not quite the answer to your question, but it may be interesting for you to consider using [Dictionaries.jl](https://github.com/andyferris/Dictionaries.jl) package, which provides more convenient means to work with dictionaries than Base Dict.

For example, in `Dictionaries.jl` notation your question can be solved as follows

```
using Dictionaries

d = dictionary(['a' => 1, 'b' => 2])

map(zero, d)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my own question. As mentioned in the Julia [docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Dictionaries-1), dictionaries can be created using generators. So you can copy the keys of the original Dict and assign all the values to be 0 like so

```
d_new = Dict(i => 0 for i in keys(d))
```

See also [this](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/create-a-dictionary-from-arrays-of-keys-and-values/13908) forum post.