# Simple command to multiply all values of a dictionary by a float

Tags: julia, structure, multiplication

In Julia, you can easily multiply all values of a `Vector`, `Matrix` or `Array` `a` by a `Float64`, say 2, by:

```
a=ones(3,3)
a*=2
```

I wanted to know if this is also easily achievable for dictionaries, for instance, `Dictionary{Int,Float64}` or `Dictionary{Tuple{Int,Int},Float64}`

I know it can be done by iterating with for loops on keys and values but I want to do it "in place" like `dict*=2`. Is it possible?

Comment: BTW `a*=2` is not in-place, the in-place version would be `a .*= 2`. Best way to check these things if with BenchmarkTools and `@btime` and `@benchmark`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This in-place `map!` might be 20X faster than `replace`.

```
map!(x->2x, values(d))
```

Testing:

```
julia> @benchmark map!(x->2x, values(d)) setup=(d = Dict(1:100 .=> rand(100)))
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 10000 samples with 985 evaluations.
 Range (min … max):  59.391 ns … 154.315 ns  ┊ GC (min … max): 0.00% … 0.00%
 Time  (median):     60.508 ns               ┊ GC (median):    0.00%
 Time  (mean ± σ):   61.706 ns ±   4.912 ns  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  0.00% ± 0.00%

   █
  ▃██▆▄▄▃▃▃▃▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▁▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂ ▂
  59.4 ns         Histogram: frequency by time         86.9 ns <

 Memory estimate: 0 bytes, allocs estimate: 0.
```

vs.

```
julia> @benchmark d_mult = replace(kv -> kv[1] => kv[2]*2, d) setup=(d = Dict(1:100 .=> rand(100)))
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 10000 samples with 30 evaluations.
 Range (min … max):  916.667 ns … 274.520 μs  ┊ GC (min … max):  0.00% … 99.13%
 Time  (median):       1.153 μs               ┊ GC (median):     0.00%
 Time  (mean ± σ):     3.052 μs ±  11.919 μs  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  21.27% ±  5.50%

  ▆█▅▄▁                  ▁▂▂▃▂▄▇▆▃▁                             ▂
  █████▇▇▆▄▄▁▁▄▁▄▅▅▃▃▁▃▁▁███████████▇▇▆▆▅▅▄▄▅▆▅▅▆▄▄▅▄▃▄▄▅▅▅▆▆▆█ █
  917 ns        Histogram: log(frequency) by time       7.68 μs <

 Memory estimate: 4.72 KiB, allocs estimate: 5.
```

Comment: Note that this is a really special-cased operation, I didn't expect this to work at all. It resulted from the [discussion here](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/fast-dict-value-modification-by-accessing-dict-vals/21277/14).

Answer (score 0):

I have found a short way thanks [to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62711458/10094437):

```
d_mult = replace(kv -> kv[1] => kv[2]*2, d)
```

Maybe someone will find something even shorter (`d_mult *= 2` or similar)

Comment: To be in-place, use `replace!` instead of `replace`. In Julia the in-place versions usually have a `!` (bang) at the end of the function name to indicate they modify the parameter (usually the first parameter).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are actually referring to types like `Base.Dict{Int,Float64}`.  There is an alternative implementation of dictionaries in [Dictionaries.jl](https://github.com/andyferris/Dictionaries.jl), providing the type `Dictionary`. This type, in contrast to `Base.Dict`, is treated as an iterable over values, not keys, and therefore can be used mostly like an array:

```
julia> dict .+ 1
3-element Dictionary{String,Int64}
 "a" │ 2
 "b" │ 3
 "c" │ 4
```